# Where's Lucia at

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've  looked just about every where for Lucia but I could not find her at all. Also, I play skyrim on ps3 with no dlc or add-ons. Could this be the reason she does not appear?

Comment: [Lucia](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lucia) is added by the Hearthfire DLC. Since you don’t have any DLCs, you won’t have Lucia.

Comment: Well I do have all DLCs but it won't enable them because I'm not using legendary edition disc

Comment: I don’t know anything about the discs for PS3, but you need Hearthfire enabled to have Lucia.

Comment: My DLCs were from the legendary edition disc but I'm using the normal edition disc

Comment: I've been trying to figure out why the DLCs won't work

Comment: I don’t have a PS3, so I can’t help with that. I just know that you need Hearthfire working for Lucia to show up.

Comment: Well if u could help  me figure out y they don't work by looking it up I'd be most grateful for that

Comment: I don’t even know where to start for PS3 questions like that. I only play on PC.

Comment: All u have to do is search it up. Also, I would do it on my phone but my Wi-Fi sucks

Answer (score 3):

You said you don't have any DLCs enabled. Lucia won't be in the game unless they're enabled.